# Oracle Apex 5 invalid Ajax call?

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I have a few proccesses and dynamic actions and now after I click a button to submit, an error pops up saying 'Invalid Ajax call!' What do you think is going on guys?

Comment: Most probably one of your dynamic actions has an error. Disable them one by one and find what is the problem. We can't help if you don't give us an exact code or process that gives that error.

Comment: Plus, enable debug and have the developer console on your browser open. You'll be able to see the dynamic actions firing off, so you can identify the one responsible. Furthermore, you'll be able to look in the debug logs and see if anything goes wrong server-side.

Comment: Thank you for the response guys. I've been able to fix the issue by deleting a dynamic action. Thanks again.